# How to set default value appearing in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, drop-down-menu

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898814/setting-default-selection-of-a-dropdown-menu-with-d3) answer which says to do this:

```
.property("selected", function(d){ return d === defaultOptionName; })
```

But this isn't working for me. I'm trying to create a simple drop down and create a default value to be the text that initially appears on the drop down. This is what I'm doing:

```js
    var dropdown = d3.select("#dropDown")
        .insert("select", "svg")
        .attr('id', 'dropDownId')
        .on("change", dropdownChange);

    dropdown.selectAll("option")
        .data(cols)
        .enter().append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d;
        });
        dropdown.property("selected", "some default value");
```

For some reasons, the first value in cols is what still shows up.
How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: `selected` is a property of the `option` tag

Comment: @rioV8 I tried substituting selected for property and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't working for me. I use the .property() on the option tag and it still did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this...

```
dropdown.property("selected", "some default value");
```

... you have to ask yourself: what is `dropdown`? It's a D3 selection, that's clear, but **what** selection?

Let's see:

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#dropDown")
    .insert("select", "svg")
    //etc...
```

Therefore, `dropdown` refers to the `<select>`, not to the options.

On top of that, you cannot set...

```
dropdown.property("selected", "some default value");
```

The `selected` property is a **boolean** of a given option.

**Solution**: create a new selection for the `<option>`s:

```
var options = dropdown.selectAll("option")
    .data(cols)
    .enter()
    //etc...
```

And then:

```
options.property("selected", function(d){
    return d === "some default value");
});
```

Where `d === "some default value"` will return `true` or `false` for each datum.

Alternatively, you don't need to name the selection (but it's a good idea doing so), just add that method to the chain.

Here is a demo:

```js
var cols = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobaz"]

var dropdown = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr('id', 'dropDownId');

var options = dropdown.selectAll("option")
  .data(cols)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

options.property("selected", function(d){return d === "foobar"});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```