# How to set default value appearing in dropdown list with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978457/how-to-set-default-value-appearing-in-dropdown), I am trying to set the selected value for a dropdown using D3. I have tried to replicate the answer gvien in that question. The only difference in my example (that I can see) is that the dropdown option 'value' and 'text' attributes are not the same and are populated by an array. The function setting the value would appear to be wrong `function(d){return d === chosenCountry}` but I can't work out what the appropriate function should be.

```
          var chosenCountry = BF";
          var countryList = [[ 1, "BW", "Botswana"], [ 2, "BF", "Burkina Faso"],[ 3, "CV", "Cabo Verde"],[ 4, "CM", "Cameroon"],[ 5, "CG", "Congo"]];

          var dropdown = d3.select('#dropDown')
            .insert("select", "svg")
            .attr('id', 'dropDownId');

          var options = dropdown.selectAll('option')
            .data(countryList)
            .enter()
            .append('option')
            .attr('value', (d) => d[1])
            .text((d) => d[2]);

          options.property("selected", function(d){return d === chosenCountry});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is an array of arrays, where the 2-letter country code (probably ISO alpha-2) is the second item in each inner array. Therefore, all you need is the correct index:

```
options.property("selected", function(d) {
    return d[1] === chosenCountry
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var chosenCountry = "BF";
var countryList = [
  [1, "BW", "Botswana"],
  [2, "BF", "Burkina Faso"],
  [3, "CV", "Cabo Verde"],
  [4, "CM", "Cameroon"],
  [5, "CG", "Congo"]
];

var dropdown = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr('id', 'dropDownId');

var options = dropdown.selectAll('option')
  .data(countryList)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .attr('value', (d) => d[1])
  .text((d) => d[2]);

options.property("selected", function(d) {
  return d[1] === chosenCountry
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And just like that, it worked! I could have sworn I tried this.  Obrigado Gerardo!